# "Напомнить" или "надпомнить"? Правильное произношение

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Многие говорят "надпомни". Так все-таки: над- или на-?

Comment: Никогда не слышал вариант "надпомни".

Answer (score 1):

Это не общеупотребительное слово; оно находится как элемент **говора** русскоязычных народов Камчатки.

А. П. Каргина
СОБСТВЕННО ДИАЛЕКТНАЯ ГЛАГОЛЬНАЯ ЛЕКСИКА
(ОПЫТ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФИЧЕСКОГО ОПИСАНИЯ
НА МАТЕРИАЛЕ ГОВОРОВ КАМЧАДАЛОВ)
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/sobstvenno-dialektnaya-glagolnaya-leksika-opyt-leksikograficheskogo-opisaniya-na-materiale-govorov-kamchadalov/pdf

В этой статье представлен фрагмент словаря диалектных глаголов из говора камчамдалов, со ссылкой на
*Словарь русского камчатского наречия /под ред. К. М. Браславца, Л. В. Шатуновой [и др.]. — Хабаровск: Хабаровский гос. пед. ин-т, 1977, c. 106:*

> **Надпомнить.** «Напомнить. — И мэня и-и их там натпомните /В-К./»